# Google Cloud Function not receiving input from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have incoming data to my Google Cloud Function and for some reason, my Google Cloud Function is getting the input from the client side in an incorrect format and is causing it to pass an undefined value to a web scraper I am attempting to build. I have tried passing the data as input = JSON.parse(req.body.input) and destructing it from the req.body and then parsing it and that did not work either. Attached here is the Google Cloud Function code as well as my client-side request (I think the client-side is OK, but I am a newbie so I could be completely off. The URL being passed into the fetch isn't the real URL, not posting it because I don't want that URL out in the open.) Any help for this struggling junior would be super appreciated!

Google Cloud Function

```
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

exports.webScrape = async (req, resp) => {
    resp.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    console.log('working woot woot')
    console.log(req.body)
resp.send('hello world')
};
```

Client-side request

````
      try {
        this.$emit("loading", true);
        console.log("getting the scraper");
        console.log(`here is input ${input}`);
        //" "" "
        const response = await fetch(
          "myURL",
          {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Allow-control-allow-origin": "*",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ input }),
          }```
````

Comment: So what does your log show? I would suggest reducing this to a [mcve] - a function which *just* logs its input, and a more complete piece of Javascript which hard-codes the request. (Aside from anything else, I'd remove the whole of `scrapeSite` for now.) At the moment we have a very incomplete picture.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for replying. My Google Cloud Function log is showing input as undefined, which I have set to JSON.stringify(req.body.input) as I am sending from the client my input an object that I am stringifying and have called input. I'll edit the code here.

Comment: Can you try triggering the function using curl? `curl -X POST HTTP_TRIGGER_ENDPOINT -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{"name":"Jane"}'` and log `req.body` ?

Comment: I suggest you log just `req.body` to start with, rather than `req.body.input`.

Comment: I reformatted the code to only log the req.body. Using the Google Cloud Function test, I was able to see {name:'gavin'}. However when I sent the request from my client (on a localserver) I get back undefined.

Comment: I have made some progress I think. I think I might be dealing with a CORS issue since I am using a POST request. I console logged the req.method and it showed options, on my client-side I am now getting a CORS error of Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Thank you all for the input here. I ended up being able to solve it with this. Thank you!  Now to struggle on the client side.

Comment: If you are able to solve your issue, I suggest you to post an answer here and accept it so that it can help the community.

Comment: Indeed! I'll be doing that first thing tomorrow!